# Medoo, short ajax syntax

Tags: php, mysql, medoo

I have problem with Medoo framework, all work fine on localhost (php > 5.4+) but on my server I have instaled PHP 5.3+, can you help me how I can convert this code to old array version and execute code on PHP 5.3. platform.

```
$database = new medoo array(
    // required
    'database_type' => 'mysql',
    'database_name' => 'mytable',
    'server' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',

 // optional
    'port' => 3306,
    'charset' => 'utf8',
        'option' => [
        PDO::ATTR_CASE => PDO::CASE_NATURAL
    ]
);


$database->insert("table", [
    "project_name" => "Some text",
    "project_owner" => "Some Text",
    "project_time" => "10/10/2014",
    "project_target" => "- Target one, - Target two, - Target three",
    "project_details" => "This is my project."
]);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<?php
require  'medoo.php';

$database = new medoo(array(
    'database_type' => 'mysql',
    'database_name' => 'test',
    'server' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'testu',
    'password' => 'asdf'


));

$database->insert("table", array(
    "project_name" => "x",
    "project_owner" => "x",
    "project_time" => "x",
    "project_target" => "x",
    "project_details" => "x"
))
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace the brackets with an array call. All the brackets are a short form for array.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: Yes, first I do this and do not want work.

$database = new medoo(array(
 // required
 'database_type' => 'mysql',
 'database_name' => 'mytable',
 'server' => 'localhost',
 'username' => 'root',
 'password' => ''


));

Comment: Exist and show error: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting ')' in /home/test/public_html/sql/index.php on line 13